# Why should cmdlets not use the Console API?

Tags: powershell

According to the [MSDN for Strongly Encouraged Development Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Cmdlets should not use the [Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

Why is this?

If I write `[Console]::Write("test")`, it works just as well as

```
Write-Host "test"
```

EDIT:
It's well known that `Write-Host` should be avoided. When MSDN says to not use the Console API, is it safe to assume that they are implying that we should not use `Write-Host` either since that uses the Console API behind the scenes?

Answer (score 10):

The main reason you shouldn't use *console*-related functionality is that **not all PowerShell host environments are *consoles*.**

While the *typical* use case is to run PowerShell in a console, PowerShell does not *need* a console and can cooperate with different kinds of host environments.

Thus, for your code to remain portable, it shouldn't assume the existence of a *console*.

**It is safe, however, to assume the existence of (the abstraction called) *host*, which PowerShell exposes via the automatic `$HOST` variable.**
The **capabilities of hosts vary**, however, which has historically created problems even when *not* using the console API directly, but its PowerShell abstraction, `Write-Host` - see below.

---

**PowerShell provides a *hosting API***,

> with which **the PowerShell runtime can be embedded inside other applications**. These applications can then use PowerShell functionality to implement certain operations, including those exposed via the graphical interface.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell

**The regular PowerShell console** using the *Console Window Host* (`conhost.exe`) on Windows is therefore **just *one* implementation of a PowerShell host** - the *PowerShell ISE* is another example, as is the *Microsoft Exchange Server management GUI* (2007+).

---

**As for `Write-Host`:**

**Up to PSv4**, as the name suggests, it **used to write to the *host* - which *may or may not be a console*** - so **`Write-Host` could actually *fail* on hosts that don't support *user interaction***; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24290813/45375).

**Starting with PSv5, `Write-Host` is safe to use**, because it now writes to the newly introduced, host-independent information stream (number `6`) - see [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) and the next section.

Note that `Write-Host` still does and always has generated output *outside* of the normal PowerShell *output* stream - its output is meant to be "commentary" (feedback to the user) rather than *data*.

While `Write-Host` is *safe* to use in PSv5+, it exist for *backward compatibility*, so **instead consider using

`Write-Information -InformationAction Continue` or using `Write-Information` with preference variable `$InformationPreference` set to `Continue`**, because:

- "Write-*Host*" is now a bit of a misnomer, given that it doesn't actually *directly* write to the *host* anymore.
- `Write-Host`, in the interest of backward compatibility, doesn't integrate with the `$InformationPreference` preference variable - see below.
- `Write-Host` still offers console-inspired formatting parameters (`-ForegroundColor`, `-BackgroundColor`), which not all hosts (ultimately) support.

---

**`Write-Host` vs. `Write-Information`:**

<sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for his help with the following.</sup>

**[`Write-Information`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn998020(v=wps.650).aspx), introduced in PSv5, is the cmdlet that fully integrates with the new, host-independent *information stream*** (number `6`).
Notably, **you can now *redirect and thus capture* `Write-Information` / `Write-Host` *output* by using `6>`**, something that wasn't possible with `Write-Host` in PSv4-.
Also note that this redirection works even with `$InformationPreference`'s default value, `SilentlyContinue`, which only governs the *display*, not the *output* aspect (only using common parameter `-InformationAction Ignore` truly suppresses *writing* to the stream).

In line with how PowerShell handles errors and warnings, the *display* behavior of `Write-Information` is controllable via the new `$InformationPreference` preference variable / the new common `-InformationAction` cmdlet parameter.
**`Write-Information`'s *default* behavior is to be *silent*** - `$InformationPreference` defaults to `SilentlyContinue`.

Note that `Write-Information` has no direct formatting parameters<sup>[1]</sup> and instead offers *keyword tagging* with the `-Tags` parameter<sup>[2]</sup>
.

By contrast, for backward compatibility, **`Write-Host` effectively behaves like

`Write-Information -InformationAction Continue`**, i.e., it ***outputs by default*, and the *only* way to silence it is to use `Write-Host -InformationAction Ignore`**<sup>[3]</sup>
 - it does *not* respect an `$InformationPreference` value of `SilentlyContinue` (it does, however, respect the other values, such as `Inquire`).

---

<sup>[1] PetSerAl points out that you *can* pass formatting information to `Write-Information`, but only in an obscure fashion that isn't even documented as of PSv5.1; e.g.:

`Write-Information -MessageData ([System.Management.Automation.HostInformationMessage] @{Message='Message'; ForegroundColor='Red'}) -InformationAction Continue`</sup>

<sup>[2] Note how parameter name "Tags" actually violates one of the [strongly encouraged cmdlet development guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx): it should be "Tag" (singular).</sup>

<sup>[3] PetSerAl explains that this behavior stems from `Write-Host` passing the `PSHOST` tag to [`Cmdlet.WriteInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt659129(v=vs.85).aspx) behind the scenes.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`[Console]::Write` or `Write-Host` are [basically the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8755614/2412846). They both write a message to the console which can be seen on the screen.

The basic reason why this is discouraged is that it breaks the workflow. The output of a `Write-Host` cmdlet can't be piped or used further. Now if the script runs on a machine without graphical output or similar constraints the command is lost.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755497/which-should-i-use-write-host-write-output-or-consolewriteline) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754069/powershell-difference-between-write-host-and-write-output) thread, you should therefore rather use `Write-Output`, which sends the output message to the pipeline where it can be further used. Further, you can use exceptions if your message is meant to signal an error.

Comment: Are you saying that both [Console]::Write and Write-Host break the workflow and can't be piped further? That's fine, what I'm interested in is why we shouldn't use [Console]::Write if it does the same thing as Write-Host.

Comment: The message, as I understand, is: use none of the two.

Comment: The MSDN article doesn't say to not use Write-Host, it says to not use the Console API. Do you think since Write-Host uses the Console API behind the scenes, that they are insinuating that we should not use that either?

Comment: You're right, this is a bit vague. My line of thinking was, if you shouldn't use `[console]::write`, and `[console]::write` is basically the same as `Write-Host`, so don't use both. But it's the second assumption you're questioning, I know ... this where I refered to another SO answer, but that's far from being sure ;-)

Comment: `[Console]::Write` and `Write-Host` _used to be_ essentially the same, up to PowerShell v4. Since not all PowerShell hosts are consoles, `Write-Host` _used to_ potentially break your code.
Starting in PowerShell v5, `Write-Host` is safe to use with all hosts, but it's better to use `WriteInformation -InformationAction Continue`.

Comment: While it's important to understand the difference between printing to the console (`Write-Host`) and sending data to the success output stream (implicitly, and with `Write-Output`), there's nothing
with _intentionally_ using `Write-Host` to simply supply _supplemental information_, _outside_ of the output data stream. Indeed, that is the mechanism that the new _information stream_ (number `6`) and the `Write-Information` cmdlet formalize.