# How do I print a file's name/path before deleting it?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that will delete a file that is at least X days old. I was wondering how I would alter it to print the file before deleting it. The script is

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)
$path = "\\noc2-storage\IT_Backup\Daily_SQL\"                                                #"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
echo "Deleting files: "
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force


# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: Define "print" - output to the screen, or actually paper copy?

Comment: output to the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach - and the one that is *generally* applicably - is to **use the `-Verbose` [common parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters)**:

```
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Deleting files:"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | 
 Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | 
  Remove-Item -Force -Verbose
```

Note that in PSv3+ you can simplify this somewhat by using the `-Files` switch with `Get-ChildItem`, which directly limits the output to files only, which then allows simplification of the `Where-Object` call to a so-called *comparison statement*:

```
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Deleting files:"
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $path -Recurse -Force | 
 Where-Object CreationTime -lt $limit | 
  Remove-Item -Force -Verbose
```

If you *only* want to echo what *would* be deleted - i.e., **to perform a dry run -  use the `-WhatIf` common parameter** with `Remove-Item`, instead of `-Verbose`.

---

Also note that I've replaced `echo "Deleting files: "` with `Write-Verbose -Verbose "Deleting files:"`.

In PowerShell, `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output`, which writes to the *success stream*, which is where output *data* is meant to go.

In fact, writing to that stream is the *default* action, so your command could be simplified to just:

```
"Deleting files: "    # implicitly output the string to the success stream
```

That said, *status* messages such as the above do *not* belong in the success stream, and using the separate stream for *verbose* output is one option.

`Write-Verbose -Verbose` generates such verbose output explicitly, but the usual mechanism is to let a function / cmdlet's `-Verbose` common parameter or the `$VerbosePreference` preference variable drive whether verbose output should be shown or not.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I would like to add a message stating how many files have been deleted. Is there an easy way to add this option to the script; if a file has been deleted, add +1 to a count.

Comment: @kevorski: If you add `-ov files` (`-OutVariable files`) to the `Where-Object` call, information about all target files is saved in collection `$files`. `$files.Count` will then tell you how many files were targeted. If this doesn't fully answer your follow-up question, please post a _new_ question (and feel free to notify me here).

Answer (score 0):

For this - you could modify the command you already have pretty easily.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)
$path = "\\noc2-storage\IT_Backup\Daily_SQL\"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }
ForEach ($file in $files) {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "Deleting: $file"
  Remove-Item -force $file
}


# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: While PSv5 has made `Write-Host` _less_ [harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) (with its ability to suppress/capture its output), it's still the wrong tool to use in most cases, including this one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I've changed the script to use write-verbose instead of write-host.  Have any useful links handy on why Write-Verbose is superior to Write-Host?

Comment: All cmdlets support `-Verbose` directly, so there's no need for a `ForEach-Object` - which is another reason to avoid `Write-Host`, because the `-Verbose` common parameter gives you the status output for free. Here's the [`Write-Verbose` help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose), which doesn't provide too much conceptual information, however. The blog post I've already linked to has more information, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40034706/45375) of mine has more about `Write-Host`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to print the file name and don't want to print the file contents: 
Have you tried passing `-verbose` to `Remove-Item`?