# Boolean flag to show or ignore PowerShell GUI

Tags: xml, wpf, powershell

I have a PowerShell script with a WPF GUI that allows the users to enter values and choose from drop-down lists. It works great, but some users want to bypass it and run the script manually (enter their own values directly into the script).

Right now the structure is:

```
#A bunch of XML and PowerShell that generates the GUI

$WPFbutton.Add_Click({

#Variables that get populated by the GUI

#The rest of the script

})
```

I want to add something like:

`$UseGUI = $true`

at the top of the script that they can change to false, which will cause the script to ignore the XML and button click line.

I was thinking I could surround the XML stuff in an if statement based on `$UseGUI` but that doesn't help with the button click part.

One thing I know would work is copy and pasting the entire script to another if statement based on `$UseGUI`. The issue there is it would double the script size, and it's already 2000 lines.

Comment: you should try add optional params, and then check if they are null before prompting with the GUI, you'll need to re-write a good chunk of your code from the sounds of it though.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use a function and parameters to identify if the person using the script wants to use the GUI or has supplied the correct information by themselves:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Interface',
               Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 0)]
    [switch]
    $UseGUI,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'CommandLine',
               Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $Person
)

function SayHelloTo ($User)
{
    Write-Output "Hello $User"
}

if ($UseGUI)
{
    #A bunch of XML and PowerShell that generates the GUI

    $WPFbutton.Add_Click({

        #Variables that get populated by the GUI

        #The rest of the script

        $variable = "jdope"

        SayHello -User $variable

    })
}
else
{
    SayHello -User $Person
}
```

The parameter sets will prevent the script from being called with both options so when you check if `UseGUI` is `$True` you will know to show the GUI (and get the input to call the function) or call the function with the input.

To use the GUI call the script with `-UseGUI`

```
.\MyPowerShellWpfScript -UseGUI
```

To supply the `Person` information and bypass the GUI use

```
.\MyPowerShellWpfScript -Person "jdope"
```

Comment: I like the approach in principle, but please, please don't use `Write-Host` unless there's a good reason to do so (and there are few). Why would `-UseGUI` need to support _pipeline_ input? If anything, it should be `-Person`, though you'd need  a `process` block in either case. From the quibbles department: _interface_ is not the same as _interactive_.

Comment: @mklement0 What's wrong with Write-Host? I use it quite a bit for output to give the status of the script.

Comment: The danger is that it may mislead beginners to think that `Write-Host` is the way to output _data_ in PowerShell (analogous to `echo` in traditional shells), whereas it _bypasses_ the (success) output stream. This confusion is very common and, I think, worth avoiding.

Comment: Some background info in [this blog post](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) and in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40034706/45375) of mine.

Comment: Ah, yes agreed, i've been doing quite a lot of form work lately with PowerShell and the only way to pass information to the console from the form is to use `Write-Host`. I'll update the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for updating. A final thought: While `Write-Output` does write to the success stream, its use is rarely necessary, because anything not explicitly captured or redirected writes to the output stream _by default_, so the idiomatic PowerShell way would be to just use `"Hello `$User"` by itself.