# Azure Function Connect-PnpOnline using Password for app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I created a powershell script to connect to my sharepoint site online.
Having enabled two-factor authentication, I set a password for the app for authentication and used it in the Connect-PnpOnline command.

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "myappapassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object PSCredential ("my@username.com", $securePassword)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TenantSiteURL$SiteRelativeURL -Credentials $credentials
```

On the local computer I don't get any errors, but when I try to run it in Azure Function I get:

```
 Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password
```

Comment: You can refer to [Web Login for Multi Factor Authentication](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#web-login-for-multi-factor-authentication) and [Interactive for Multi Factor Authentication](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#interactive-for-multi-factor-authentication)

Comment: I cannot use web login because the script is hosted in azure function. Running the script on the local machine all methods work (both with credentials and weblogin)

Comment: You can refer to a similar GitHub issue: [Cannot connect with credentials](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/61)

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I have read the discussion carefully but couldn't quite figure out how to fix the problem.

Checking I have the latest version of PnpOnline.
How can I authenticate my app? 
I have read that there is a way to use Managed Identity but how can I?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the few workaround to solve the above issue:

- Please make sure that you have uploaded your pnp powershell module to Azure function .
  By Navigating to Azure function >Advance tool>Kudu console> wwwroot folder > Create new folder copy and paste your modules that have in your local.
- Add your service account user name and password in configuration of Azure function.
- Try to replace the following `cmd` in your cmdlt:

`$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($serviceAccountEmail, $SecurePassword)`

- To use ***managed identity*** you can refer this [***`Blog`***](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/azurefunctions.html#by-using-a-managed-identity)

For more information please refer the below links :

- MS DOC: [***Connect-PnpOnine***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps), [***Granting access via Azure AD App-Only***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)
- MS Q&A: [***Connecting with PnP PowerShell(without username and password)***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/311751/azure-ad-authentication-and-authorization-using-th.html)

Comment: I get: ERROR: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: 

Exception             : 
    Type        : System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException
    ErrorRecord : 
        Exception             : 
            Type    : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException

Comment: Hello @blacky99 , For the above error could you please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290813/how-can-i-execute-scripts-in-a-code-created-powershell-shell-that-has-write-host) and [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.promptingexception?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)